# Auto-compile other .py files imported as packages?

Tags: python

I have two .py files I wrote that I've imported into a third .py file to use:

```
(The top of driver.py)
import wafer_diagram
import LightIV
```

wafer_diagram.py and LightIV.py contain functions that I'm using in driver.py. However, whenever I have a cleared/restarted kernel, I have to run each individual .py file, otherwise they aren't defined in driver.py. Is there a way to automatically do this when I run driver.py? I am using Spyder with python 3.8. Thanks!

Edit: To clarify, after running wafer diagram.py and LightIV.py, I am able to use the functions in driver.py without issue. However, if I restart my kernel, and then try running driver.py, an error will throw that the two modules do not exist.

Comment: The `import` statement takes a module name, not a file name. Try `wafer_diagram` instead of `wafer_diagram.py`.

Comment: Sorry about that! I made a mistake in my initial post - I have the files imported the way that you mentioned; I will edit the post to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

I was being very silly! Although I imported my other files, I was not calling on their functions correctly. For example, for the function print_struct() from LightIV.py, I would write in driver.py:

```
import LightIV
print_struct()
```

Instead, I should have written:
import LightIV
LightIV.print_struct()

The reason that I was able to get away with this for so long was likely due to how Spyder saves variables. I would run LightIV.py and wafer_diagram.py, "saving" their functions, and then using them later on instead of properly importing them.